# Coding a java game - JFrame not working as expected

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe

I'd like some help in locating the error I'm making here. I'm relatively new to using Swing and this is the first game I've tried to make.

The problem is as follows: the code compiles fine, but when I run this code, nothing displays in the frame. I've noticed that if I remove the call to grabFrame in the Player class, and uncomment g.drawRect(...), that a rectangle will display in the frame, but when I add the grabFrame call back in, again nothing displays.

GamePanel:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GamePanel extends JFrame {

    final static int GWIDTH = 512;
    final static int GHEIGHT = 512;
    static final Dimension screenSize = new Dimension(GWIDTH, GHEIGHT);
    JavaGame game;

    public GamePanel () {
        this.setTitle("Game");
        this.setSize(screenSize);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        game = new JavaGame(screenSize);
        add(game);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {   
        GamePanel gp = new GamePanel();
    }
}
```

JavaGame:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Graphics;    
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    class JavaGame extends JPanel {

        // Game variables
        private GameEngine gameEngine;

        public JavaGame(Dimension screenSize) {
            this.setPreferredSize(screenSize);
            gameEngine = new GameEngine();
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            gameEngine.draw(g);
        }
    }
```

GameEngine:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class GameEngine {

    Player p1;
    public GameEngine () {
        p1 = new Player();
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        drawCharacters(g);
    }

    private void drawCharacters(Graphics g) {
            p1.draw(g);
    }
}
```

Player:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Player {

    private BufferedImage frame;
    private URL frameURL;

    public Player() {
        try {
            frameURL = new File("C:/Users/admin/workspace/JavaGame/src/civ_walk_south.png").toURI().toURL();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        grabFrame();

    }

    private void grabFrame() {
            try {
             frame = ImageIO.read(frameURL);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {          
        g.drawImage(frame, 50, 50, null);
        //g.drawRect(50, 50, 50, 50); // put this here for testing, when uncommented it only works if call to grabFrame() is removed from constructor
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding:

```
public GamePanel () {
    this.setTitle("Game");
    this.setSize(screenSize);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setVisible(true);  // *****
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    game = new Game(screenSize);
    add(game);
}
```

Call `setVisible(true)` on your JFrame **after** adding all components, not before.

So,....

```
public GamePanel () {
    this.setTitle("Game");
    //  this.setSize(screenSize);  // **** don't set sizes like this
    this.setResizable(false);
    // this.setVisible(true);  // *****
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    game = new Game(screenSize);
    add(game);
    pack();  // **** this should size the GUI to the preferred sizes
    setVisible(true); // **** call this here ****
}
```

---

Also, have you tested to see if the image obtained is null or not before drawing it?

This smells funny to me as your image path appears to be in a location that will be included inside of the jar file:

```
frameURL = new File("C:/Users/admin/workspace/JavaGame/src/civ_walk_south.png")
              .toURI().toURL();
```

Why not get your image as a resource and not first as a file?

Comment: Thanks! That worked. It was the removal of `this.setSize(screenSize);` and adding `pack();` that made the difference. Can you explain what you mean by "Why not get your image as a resource and not first as a file?"

Comment: @user2278963: You're welcome. Regarding your question above, have you made a jar file of your program, or do you plan to? If so, and if the image will be part of the jar file, then it cannot be read as a file and should be read as a resource since files don't exist in jar files.

Comment: Learning about jar files will be the next thing on my list, then. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

put `add(game)` at the topit might also help to `setVisible(true)` at the very end as well. You also want to call a `pack` method as well

In the java game class don't declare `this.setPreferredSize(screensize)` in the java game class instead put it in game panel class also don't just call `setPreferredSize()` you alos want `setMaximumSize()` and `setMinimumSize()` so your game panel class should look like this.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GamePanel extends JFrame {

final static int GWIDTH = 512;
final static int GHEIGHT = 512;
static final Dimension screenSize = new Dimension(GWIDTH, GHEIGHT);
JavaGame game;

public GamePanel () {
    game = new JavaGame(screenSize); 

    game.setPreferredSize(screenSize);
    game.setMaximumSize(screenSize);
    game.setMinimumSize(screenSize);       

    add(game);
    this.setTitle("Game");
    this.setSize(screenSize);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main (String[] args) {   
    GamePanel gp = new GamePanel();
}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The use of setXxxSize isn't highly recommended, instead, the OP should be encouraged to override the getXxxSize method instead